# Simple Hive query is empty

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a csv log file. After loading it into Hive using this sentence:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE iprange(id STRING, ip STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\,' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/user/hadoop/expandediprange/';
```

I want to perfom a simple query like:

```
select * from iprange where ip="0.0.0.2";
```

But I get an empty result.

I'm running Hive on HDFS, should I use HBase?
My conclusion is that it's got something to do with the table size. Log file is 160 MB, and the generated table in Hive has 8 million rows. If I try to create myself a smaller file and load it to Hive it will work.

Any idea of what is wrong?

Edit: I forgot to say that it's running on Amazon Elastic MapReduce using a small instance.

Comment: My guess is that your delimiter is wrong in the table definition.  Try "select ip from iprange limit 10".  If you get all nulls, you probably need to change the delimiter.

Comment: Hi Chris. If I do that query it works. What is more surprising, I I do this query:  select * from iprange where id="23"; This is querying by ID instead of IP, it works.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but are you sure there are data for ip "0.0.0.2"?

Comment: Can you show the output of a small select query? Sometimes it is hard to catch with untrained eye the problem with a wrong delimiter.

Comment: Olaf, this is the output of: select * from iprange limit 10; (Sorry about the new lines) it's <ID> <IP>               146 0.0.0.0 
146 0.0.0.1 
146 0.0.0.2 
146 0.0.0.3 
146 0.0.0.4 
146 0.0.0.5 
146 0.0.0.6 
146 0.0.0.7 
146 0.0.0.8 
146 0.0.0.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was not a Hive issue really. I'm using the output of a Hadoop job as input, and in that job I was writing the output in the key, leaving the value as an empty string:

```
context.write(new Text(id + "," + ip), new Text(""));
```

The problem is that Hadoop inserts a tab character by default between the key and the value, and as field is a string it took the tab as well, so I had a trailing tab in every line. I discovered it using Pig as it embraces the output with ().

The solution for me is to set the separator to another character, as I have only two fields I write one in the key and the other one in the value, and set the separator to ",":

```
conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", ",");
```

Maybe its possible to trim these things in Hive.