# HiveQL query returns no results and no errors

Tags: hadoop, join, hive, hiveql

I am running Apache Hadoop 2.6.0 on Ubuntu 14.0 and I have a table created in Hive 0.13.0 as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recipes_hive.cuisine (
ID INT COMMENT 'Cuisine ID.', 
name STRING COMMENT 'Cusine name - primary key.', 
area STRING COMMENT 'Name of the area of origin - foreign key.', 
scope STRING COMMENT 'Either country or area.') 
COMMENT 'Table containing cuisines data.'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

And I fill it with data with statement:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'path_to_file/CUISINE.csv'
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE recipes_hive.cuisine;
```

My database has several such tables all created and filled with same procedure. When running simple queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM cuisine
```

or even with certain conditions in WHERE clause I get the results as expected but running more complex queries I get squat. For example:

```
SELECT cuisine.name, SUM(IF (ingredient.category = "fruit",1,2))/count(*) AS      PERC 
FROM cuisine JOIN recipe ON recipe.cuisine = cuisine.name JOIN part_of ON part_of.id_recipe = recipe.id JOIN ingredient ON ingredient.name = part_of.ingredient 
GROUP BY cuisine.name 
ORDER BY PERC DESC
```

, or:

```
SELECT ingredient.id, ingredient.name 
FROM cuisine JOIN recipe ON recipe.cuisine = cuisine.name JOIN part_of ON part_of.id_recipe = recipe.id JOIN ingredient ON ingredient.name = part_of.ingredient 
WHERE ingredient.id IN (
SELECT ingredient.id 
FROM cuisine c JOIN recipe ON recipe.cuisine = c.name JOIN part_of ON part_of.id_recipe = recipe.id JOIN ingredient ON ingredient.name = part_of.ingredient 
WHERE c.name = "Pakistan") AND cuisine.name = "Bangladesh"
```

The first example calculates some percentage and the second one checks for mutual elements.

The MapReduce and Hadoop get invoked properly and they return no error. The output ends with:

```
Execution completed successfully
MapredLocal task succeeded
OK
Time taken: 122.119 seconds
```

I have checked the web and people had similar issues as I do. I checked:

[Hive Table returning empty result set on all queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094261/hive-table-returning-empty-result-set-on-all-queries)

[Simple Hive query is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347699/simple-hive-query-is-empty)

but failed to get my issue resolved. The data is in fact in the HDFS and as mentioned before it works on simple queries.

So either there is something wrong with my Hive instance or my queries are not written correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Best regards.

Comment: How about breaking the query into smaller temporary tables ? Or is there a requirement to fetch the result in a single query ?

Comment: Not a requirement but I would like to do it in one single query because I am making a comparison of query execution times on three different systems and I would like it to be unified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have Cuisine table containing ID = {1,2,3} and Recipe table containing ID = {5,6,7} , then even though these tables are non-empty, we still get no rows returned when we do INNER JOIN Cuisine.ID = Recipe.ID (as the ID's are different in the 2 tables)
Can you please check that there is no such condition.

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM cuisine c JOIN recipe ON recipe.cuisine = c.name WHERE c.name = "Pakistan";

--- must return > 0 

select count(1) from recipe as recipe
JOIN part_of ON part_of.id_recipe = recipe.id ;

--- must return > 0 

select count(1) from part_of as part_of
JOIN ingredient ON ingredient.name = part_of.ingredient ;

--- must return > 0
```

So the inner query returns a row when all the count(*) are non-zero. Now test the outer select :

```
SELECT ingredient.id, ingredient.name 
FROM cuisine JOIN recipe ON recipe.cuisine = cuisine.name JOIN part_of ON part_of.id_recipe = recipe.id JOIN ingredient ON ingredient.name = part_of.ingredient 
WHERE ingredient.id = <inner query result> and cuisine.name = "Bangladesh";
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the resulting join will be non-empty. Since, you have implemented inner joins, even if one table has missing records, the entire result set is 0. Try adding a left join with "IS NULL" to validate that all the tables contribute to the result set. If all the child tables have non-null values in their respective columns post-join, then the query is good.

Comment: I don't fully understand your answer. Are you suggesting that one of the tables might be empty and thus return 0 rows?

Comment: I checked my data and all strings have something added to them probably a '\t' and that is probably why I get 0 rows in return. Once I figure out how to remove it. it should work. Thanks for your help and excuse my absence. 

Even though my query returns no results, and it is a simple query that works fine, it takes a long time to execute. For example, the same query in MySQL executes in less than a second but in Hive it takes almost a minute. Is that common?

Comment: Hive is meant for large data processing. If your tables are smaller, a relational DBMS like MySQL will beat Hive in time. But, as the data grows, you will see Hive performing better. It also has to do with how the 2 systems are setup. If you have single node hive system, whereas MySQL is production grade, you can see performance differences. Please post you server configuration for Hive and Mysql , we can discuss more on this.

Comment: Use like operation if the data is smaller. Then there is no need to remove the '\t'. It is possibly  the column delimiter. But, use a like operator if the data is smaller and you just need to see the results for now. you can rectify the file creation process or the ddl structure before you deploy to production. Select * from table1 as A left outer join table2 as B on A.id like B.id ||'%'; Need to test the query out though.